# Explicit annotations of references vs values in rust

Tags: rust

So in Rust, one thing I am puzzled with is the type inference ability when it comes to a value vs a reference. For example,

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("h1");
    let s2 = &s1;
    println!("string is {}", s1);
}
```

The borrow checker allows this to compile, but I am not sure why? Is `s2` here a value or is it being inferred as a reference to s1?

In C++, initializing a new value via a reference would create a copy, unless that variable was explicitly declared as a reference:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    std::string s1("Hello");
    std::string& s2 = s1; // reference
    std::string s3 = s2; // copy
}
```

So in rust, my question is, does type inference also apply to reference vs value situations? If so, when is when required to explicitly declare variables as references?

Comment: A struct value, and a reference to a struct value are two different types from the standpoint of the typechecker. Is that perhaps what is throwing you off?

Comment: In the rust example, is s2 inferred as a reference or is it a new value created from a reference?

Comment: `&s1` means you have a reference type.

Comment: I see so it is not needed to explicitly declare on the `let` side. Make sense now.

Comment: Another thing to clarify is that Rust typically _moves_ values as opposed to copying them. If you were to add a line `let s3 = s1` to the Rust example, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b434b04f47d10831a208c4d08d8b961b), then it would fail to compile as the value has been moved out of `s1` and into `s3`. The `Clone` trait can be used to explicitly create a new copy of a value (e.g. `let s3 = s1.clone()`), and the `Copy` trait can be used to allow implicit bit-for-bit copying (e.g. primitives like i32).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What is my type?

The type of `s2` is `&std::string::String`, more commonly expressed as simply `&String`.

`s2` is a borrow of `s1` in the form of a (read-only) reference (the `&`), and would prevent `s1` from being written to (if it were mutable) while `s2` was in scope.

## How can I determine this on my own in the future?

[Sample code on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7163bd68b9c53f36c07be91b0264e103)

If you would like to ask the compiler to reveal the type of a particular binding, a common idiom is to use `let () = some_binding;`. The compiler will give you an error, revealing the type of `some_binding`.

I noticed that the compiler seemed to 'help' by omitting the leading `&`, so as you get comfortable with Rust, I recommend trying to call a dummy function with the wrong type, which reveals the binding's full type.  Here, the compiler does reveal the full type of the calling parameter, which you can see is `&String`.

### Explicitly Declaring Types (addressing OP's comment):

Regarding explicitly declaring the type on the `let` side of a declaration, as in C++ ([see 'AAA'](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)), Rust supports something similar:

```rust
let a: u32 = 42;

// equvialent
let b = 42_u32;
```

For constructed types, the type will be whatever type the type constructor returns:

```rust
// seems somewhat redundant (since `String::new()` returns `String`) 
// but is perfectly legal
let c: String = String::new("Hello, world!");

// equivalent
let d = String::new("Hello, world!");
```

So as long as the compiler can unambiguously determine the type from the right hand side, the type can be inferred for `let`.

Note: the type specification is still mandatory for `const` bindings:

```rust
// error: despite the explicit type declaration on the RHS, the type is still required
//const foo = 42_u32;

// since the type must be explicitly defined specifying again on the RHS is redundant
// (but legal):
const foo: u32 = 42_u32;

// Rustic (idiomatic) for `const`
const bar: u32 = 42;
```

Comment: An additional point to consider: Rust does much fewer implicit type conversions than C++, so the direct translation of the third line in the OP's C++ example (copy mode) is `let s3: String = s2;` and doesn't compile. It requires an explicit call to `s2.to_string()`.